# Creating a summary row in a dojo dataGrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am curious if anyone could explain how I can generate a summary row (totals for each column or the like) with a dojo dataGrid. As far as I can understand, I need to use onBeforeRow probably, but I've not been successful thus far. A snippet of example code or a link to some reasonable documentation would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

inside onBeforeRow use the row index which is sent as an argument, using this rowIndex, grid.getItem(rowIndex) we can get the full data for that row, then you might accumulate some values from this object for displaying average kind of data.

What is the summary you are displaying , Please be more specific

**Ah, dont forget that onBeforeRow is on View object not on the Grid...**

Comment: Though computing summary data on the fly would be useful, it seems like it would be good to start with a simple case so let's say I pre-compute the summary values and pass the summary information into the data store with the rest of the data. Say the data grid is something like the number of visits on a page for a day, each row representing an hour. I would want to be able to see the total number of visits for that day in a summary row at the top (or bottom) of the table. How could I pin the row to a specific location in the data grid regardless of sorting?